# Problem with postgres in kubernetes when using password in configMap or secret

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

When I deploy postgres like the following everything is ok:

```
.
.
.
  env:
     - name: POSTGRES_USER
       value: a
.
.
.
```

But when I deploy it by configMap or secret for example:

```
        env:
          - name: POSTGRES_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: postgres
                key: username
```

when I execute psql -U a it returns:
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  role "a" does not exist

I checked environment `POSTGRES_USER` and this variable is set to `a`

Comment: I forgot to mention image version. it was postgres:12.3

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) from the PostgreSQL image:

> The only variable required is POSTGRES_PASSWORD, the rest are
> optional.

You're defining a custom role, which is okay but you're not passing the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` which is mandatory. It's possible the role is not created at all if you don't pass the password.

Another important comment from the documentation:

> Warning: the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you
> start the container with a data directory that is empty; any
> pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup.

If this is not a playground/stateless environment and you're loading existing data, the startup script won't look at the environment variables and you should use credentials that were previously configured.

Comment: tnx for your answer. but I passed the password in the ... parts. and when I pass it directly through docker environment  it works (but not works through kuber config map or secret). I think its kubernetes related problem and not related to  postgres image (imagine kubernetes starts the container and then sets the environment variable after starting the postgres).